# Move view up on TextView Edit Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, crash, swift3

I know this question has asked several times, but I'm looking for an implementation that uses Swift 3.0. To be clear I have a Text VIEW, not a text FIELD.

I tried doing something like this...

In `viewDidLoad()`:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: Selector(("keyboardWillShow")), name:NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil);
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: Selector(("keyboardWillHide")), name:NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil);
```

Then I created these methods in the ViewController:

```
func keyboardWillShow(sender: NSNotification) {
    self.view.frame.origin.y = -150
}

func keyboardWillHide(sender: NSNotification) {
    self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
}
```

I get a crash when I select the text view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify your add observer code as mentioned below.
As per Swift 3 migration guide this is the new way that should be followed to declare the add observer of notification.

**Code :**

```
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
```

I have checked this with demo code with text view and notification center.

Hope it helps ...

Happy coding ...

Answer (score 0):

use the https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager and don't care about the keyboard issues. If you still want to implement the default behaviour of the textview, please specify the crash.

Comment: This doesn't work for Swift 3.0. It says it does but I just spend 30 minutes trying to get it to work with Pods, and it didn't work. Thanks for the recommendation though.